# Kohana execute assignes null to parameter var

Tags: mysql, kohana, execute

Within Kohana model I have something like this.

```
function getDeviceIdForUserId( $user_id ) {

        $sqlQuery = "SELECT device_id  FROM users WHERE user_id =:id";            
        $query = DB::query(Database::SELECT, $sqlQuery)
                ->param(':id', $user_id);   
        echo  $user_id;                 
        $result = $query->execute()->as_array();
        echo  $user_id; 
}
```

Can anybody explain why my response is

```
22
NULL
```

It seems like after `$result = $query->execute()->as_array();` this line `$user_id` is null.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was happening but replacing this code fixed my issue

```
$result = $query->execute()->as_array();
```

to

```
$result = $query->execute()->current();
```